# Class file not found by composer and psr-4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am having very hard times understanding how to use autoloading by `psr-4`.
After loading vagrant and setting and testing all variables in `Homestead.yaml` I have prepared a file structure as the following:

```
\app
   \folder
      -- test.php
   \vendor
       \composer
       -- autoload.php
   -- index.php
   -- composer.json
```

and the following are my codes:
**index.php**

```
<?PHP 
namespace app;

require('vendor/autoload.php');

$object = new folder\test();
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "app\\": "app"
    }
}
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 
namespace app\folder;

class test 
{
    function __construct ()
    {
        echo 'construction done right.';
    }
}
```

But, after trying to visit the page, these are the error message displayed on the page:

> (!) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'app\folder\test' not found in /home/vagrant/web/sites/app/index.php on line 6
>   ( ! ) Error: Class 'app\folder\test' not found in /home/vagrant/web/sites/app/index.php on line 6

Would you help me understand and fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you have told Composer that the classes from the `app` namespace are in the `app` subdirectory but there is no `app` subdirectory.

The entire application is stored in the `app` directory and it's name doesn't really matter for the application. The classes of the `app` namespace are stored in the current directory and the sub-namespaces are stored in subdirectories with the same name.

Accordingly, your `composer.json` file should read:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": ""
    }
}
```

Or, to be more clear, you can put `.` (the current directory) as the location of the `app\` namespace:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "app\\": "."
    }
}
```

After you make the change run `composer dump-autoloader` in the main application directory and it will start working.

Comment: @Dear friends above: thank you very very much for your help and concerns. Thank you both very much again. You have saved my day and taught me a great lesson.

Answer (score 2):

To fix it for your current setup, use the following:

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "app\\": ""
    }
}
```

Your `composer.json` is in the app-directory, so there's no subdirectory named app to reference.

---

I would actually recommend to change your directory structure to the following:

```
  \app
     \src
     \folder
       -- test.php
       -- index.php
     \vendor
       \composer
         -- autoload.php
     -- index.php
     -- composer.json
```

And then in composer.json, set the following:

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "app\\": "src"
    }
}
```

This makes sure that all files belonging to your 'app' namespace are contained within a single subdirectory.

---

Finally, I would recommend you to use a vendor namespace to prevent conflicts, and to use the naming guidelines from PSR-2.

Answer (score 1):

I think you won't need PSR-4 just add `classmap`

`classmap` parameter for example :

```
"autoload": {        
    "classmap": [
        "app"
    ]
}
```

After adding this run `composer dump-autoload` and you should see a number of classes being added.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just an update... if you don't want to do above you may run

**composer dump-autoload -a**

Answer (score -1):

in composer.json try to set

```
"autoload":{
    "psr-4":{
        "": "src/"
    }
}
```

then do execute this command

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it is not working either.